# How can I sign in with X on my web site, when there are multiple accounts across providers for the same user?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on

If I have a website where it is possible to sign in with multiple different providers (Say Facebook, GitHub, Google), what do I use as the local-to-my-site unique identifier for users? For example, if these two steps happened:

1. I sign in with GitHub (For the first time) and my username is mogronalol and email is mogronalol@mogronalol.com.
2. A local-to-my-site acccount with an email address of mogronalol@mogronalol.com and username of mogronalol is created.

If I use the email address as the local unique identifier, what happens if my email address changes in GitHub to other@other.com? The same question applies to changing username also.

If I got some sort of unique ID from GitHub, and used that as the identifier, then what do I do if my email address or username changes in GitHub. Do I just updated my local-to-my-site-copy to be the same as the one on GitHub each time I log in?

Of course, this problem is worsened if I want to log in with my Facebook account as well as my GitHub account. What happens if my email address and / or username are different across both of these? How would my local site know to link the accounts together? And if things like email address are different once the accounts are linked, which one do I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, maybe you could try on some tutorial to feel how OAuth work.

After your OAuth authentication succeed, your website will receive a series of information provided by OAuth provider.[example](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash)

Within this information, there are two special columns called `uid` and `provider` used to recognize user from OAuth provider.

You will use these two columns to tell which provider the authentication come from (i.e. `facebook` or `github`), also you need to save these fields to your account columns.

Then use rest of information to create the account in your website.

For example, use OAuth provider's email as `email`(github's email as email).

After you create account, every time you login server from OAuth provider.

You only need to check `provider` and `uid` in account column.

Let's back to your question.

> If I use the email address as the local unique identifier, what happens if my email address changes in GitHub to other@other.com? The same question applies to changing username also.
>
> If I got some sort of unique ID from GitHub, and used that as the identifier, then what do I do if my email address or username changes in GitHub. Do I just updated my local-to-my-site-copy to be the same as the one on GitHub each time I log in?

Github's email or user change won't affect your login (We only check `provider` and `uid` fields to login user).

I suggest not to sync with your OAuth provider's information(We only use OAuth provider's information when create account).

If you are going to support multiple OAuth provider, I suggest you read through [this article](https://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/).

You have to separate `uid` and `provider` to other table called identity.

Each account has many identities.

I also did it before.

If you don't mind, [here](https://github.com/bamboofox/bamboofox-website/blob/master/app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb) is the sample code snippet to deal with multiple OAuth providers.

You have to think about the logic in your login flow.

For example, user has signed in and login OAuth => Link account with OAuth provider

User not signed in and login OAuth => If find user with OAuth, login, else create account using OAuth provider's information

> Of course, this problem is worsened if I want to log in with my Facebook account as well as my GitHub account. What happens if my email address and / or username are different across both of these? How would my local site know to link the accounts together? And if things like email address are different once the accounts are linked, which one do I use?

We only link account, when user is already signed in.

When you link account, you could determine to use OAuth provider's information to update account(just like you used to register account).

I suggest to use the original email not to update it from OAuth provider's information.